# Is it possible to start JSSOR slider with a different slide on a page refresh?

Tags: slider, jssor

I would like the slider to start at a different position every time the web page is loaded. I would not like to see the same first image every time the web page is loaded. Is this possible?

Comment: Please set $StartIndex to different value every time. http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: I see that I can manually set the $StartIndex to a specific number, but that does not solve my issue.  I would like $StartIndex to be set to a different (or random) number every time a user visits the page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var startIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); //Assuming that you have 4 slides in your slider

var options = {
    ...,
    $StartIndex: startIndex,
    ...
};
```